# How to force standby mode in OSX 10.13.6 if the battery level is lower than xx%

Tags: macos, shutdown, power-management, standby

How can I set my PMSET Settings and force a Standby if the battery level is lower than 25%. Or just change the popup warning if the battery level is lower than 25%. (months ago I got a warning message if the battery level was less than 5%-7%).

After a lot of battery cycle use my MacBook Pro couldn't recognize anymore when to force standby mode in order to avoid data lost while working.
My MacBook Pro turns off without warning and doesn't even go automatically into sleep mode.
I recognize the necessity of changing the battery (more than 1500 cycles), but before buying a new battery I did some SMC reset, some PRAM and staff reset.
I ran the Apple Hardware Test (long version)...
Everything seemed fine, so I bought a new battery.
Now my MacBook Pro has a new battery (did already 4 cycles), but I still have the same problem. 
If I just put my MacBook Pro on standby it's of course not a problem. It works properly.

Computer in use: MacBook Pro (Early 2011) upgraded (SSD, 2x8GB RAM, OS X 10.13.6)
I did the upgrade one year ago, so it's definitely not in common with this problem.

OS X in use: 10.13.6

The battery producer wrote that turn off are possible on first Cycles (1 to 4).
It happened, with the new Battery still turn off without warning (on battery level around 20%). And no sleep mode. It did it now for 4 cycles.

I think I have to set something to force sleep mode on 50% battery and check if it's working.

Power Management settings:

```
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              0
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms                  1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
Local:~ matthias$ sudo pmset standby 1
Local:~ matthias$ sudo pmset -g
```

Systemwide power settings:

```
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms                  1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 hibernatemode        3
```